# Oracle Apex - Read contents of an uploaded txt file

Tags: oracle, upload, oracle-apex

I am trying to read the contents of a text file that I uploaded using the page item file browser but I cannot figure out how to get the files contents.

I don't need it to be pushed into a table or anything, I just want a string represetation of it in a text area, for example. Or to be stored into a variable so I can process.

Apologies for the vagueness if any. I have tried a few ways but I am not sure, can I get the contents somehow using the WWV_FLOW_FILE?

The only solutions I have seen are using the Wizard region with the data mapping/verification breadcrumbs which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the uploaded file as a BLOB inside the `WWV_FLOW_FILE`. If you just want to show it, into lets say a text field named `P1_some_text_field`, you can simple add a procedure like this on the page where you do the upload:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(blob_content))
  INTO :P1_some_text_field
  FROM wwv_flow_files
  WHERE created_on =
    (SELECT MAX(created_on) FROM wwv_flow_files WHERE CREATED_BY = :APP_USER
    );
END;
```

Please note that this will retrieve at most the fist 32767 characters of your file.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come up with that, but unfortunately I have moved on with a different solution because the files I am working with are too large and cause the browser to hang from the processing it has to do. I am going to upload the file then initiate sql scheduler to launch a script to download the file and process it. That way, the user computer is not hanging and the process is done quicker .

Answer (score 0):

When I upload the file to WWV_FLOW_FILES, I then used a pl/sql statement to get the ID of the last file uploaded by the user and send the ID through another pl/sql statement which launches a powershell script on the server to download the file. The file is then processed on the server.